# How to extend React Component prop typing without changing all usages of React.Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to make `testID` a prop available for all `React.Component` instances for native testing. Currently, I am adding it to prop type of all the components that are using it. Is there any way where, for example I can define `react/index.d.ts` and override the Component prop type to include `{testID?: string}`?

EDIT:

```
// types/react/index.d.ts

import 'react'
import { Attributes, ClassAttributes } from 'react'

declare namespace react {
  interface IntrinsicAttributes extends Attributes {
    testID?: string
  }
  interface IntrinsicClassAttributes<T> extends ClassAttributes<T> {
    testID?: string
  }
}
```

I tried the above override, but it's not working, but if I copy the whole react typing file in and then make above changes, it works fine. So I just need proper overriding technique. Can someone please help me in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// src/types/react/index.d.ts

import * as React from 'react'

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicAttributes extends React.Attributes {
      testID?: string
    }

    interface IntrinsicClassAttributes<T> extends React.ClassAttributes<T> {
      testID?: string
    }
  }
}
```

Above override worked for me. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

For class components, create a proxy class and extend it as even static properties are inherited :

```
class Proxy extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    testId: PropTypes.string
  };
}

class SomeComponent extends Proxy {
  render() {

  }
}
```

For functional components, you cannot do this. An alternative would be to create a utility which will add it for you :

```
function withPropTypes(Component) {
    Component.propTypes = {
        testId : PropTypes.string
    };

    return Component;
}


function SomeComponent() {

}

const SomeComponentWithPropTypes = withProps(SomeComponent);
```

Note: You can use the above util for class components also.

Comment: that was my concern in the question, I don't want to change the usages of the component. Can I not somehow change in my own React declaration file.